# Bunnet/Beanie odm: replace_one with upsert

Tags: python, mongodb, odm, bunnet, beanie

What would be the equivalent of `.replace_one({"key": key}, doc, upsert=True)` in bunnet/beanie odm?

Answer (score 1):

The odm does not cover this functionality.

It uses motor under the hood, and passes only the filter, the document, and the session downstream:
https://github.com/roman-right/beanie/blob/e2d95be0843375353d6ec79a230f63d4f874ee0e/beanie/odm/queries/find.py#L948

```
        result: UpdateResult = (
            self.document_model.get_motor_collection().replace_one(
                self.get_filter_query(),
                get_dict(
                    document,
                    to_db=True,
                    exclude={"_id"},
                    keep_nulls=document.get_settings().keep_nulls,
                ),
                session=self.session,
            )
        )
```

You can try to work it around wrapping it in a bulk write. When `bulk_writer` parameter is passed to `update_one` it seems to proxy arbitrary parameters `pymongo_kwargs` downstream: https://github.com/roman-right/beanie/blob/e2d95be0843375353d6ec79a230f63d4f874ee0e/beanie/odm/queries/find.py#L980

```
        bulk_writer.add_operation(
            Operation(
                operation=ReplaceOne,
                first_query=self.get_filter_query(),
                second_query=get_dict(
                    document,
                    to_db=True,
                    exclude={"_id"},
                    keep_nulls=document.get_settings().keep_nulls,
                ),
                object_class=self.document_model,
                pymongo_kwargs=self.pymongo_kwargs,
            )
        )
```

but I would rather raised an issue or a PR to the maintainer, if I wanted to use the library, and not to fight against it.